# Stack in Java not being able to print in specific order

Tags: java, string, stack

Currently I'm working on a project that is supposed to be a reverse word guessing game. 

This is how it should work:

```
Enter a word: (input = cheese)
```

```
Your word is: _ _ _ _ _ e
What letter do you guess? (input = s)
```

The use keeps guessing the word until it is fully spelled out. If the user guesses the letter correctly it is revealed if not it is still reveled as shown below

```
Your word is: _ _ _ _ _ e
What letter do you guess?
```

```
Your word is: _ _ _ _ s e
What letter do you guess?
```

```
Your word is: _ _ _ e s e
What letter do you guess?
```

```
Your word is: _ _ e e s e
What letter do you guess?
```

```
Your word is: _ h e e s e
What letter do you guess?
```

```
Your word is: c h e e s e
Gameover!
```

⚠️ Currently I have a stack containing all the letters of the given word as shown below:⚠️   
Bottom:   c h e e s e      :Top

I currently have this code:

```java
while(guesses < letters.size()){
   System.out.print("Your word is: ");
   for(int i = 1; i < letters.size(); i++){
      System.out.print("_ ");
   }
   System.out.println(letters.peek() + test);
   System.out.println("Score: " + score);
   System.out.print("What letter do you guess? ");
   char guess = sc.next().charAt(0);
   if((Object)guess == letters.peek()){
      test += letters.pop();
      score++;
   }
   else{
      test += letters.pop();
      score--;
   }
}
```

However it is printing this:

```
Your word is: _ _ _ _ _ e
Score: 0
What letter do you guess? 
Your word is: _ _ _ _ se
Score: 0
What letter do you guess? 
Your word is: _ _ _ ees
Score: 0
What letter do you guess? 
Your word is: _ _ eese
Score: 0
What letter do you guess? 
Your word is: _ hesee
Score: 0
What letter do you guess? 
Your word is: ceseeh
Score: 0
Gameover!
```

Thank you. If any more information is needed please comment and tell me!

Comment: did you try to debug your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incomplete, so I can't be sure what and where is the issue. To answer your question I'll assume the issue is that the line `System.out.println(letters.peek() + test);` prints the word incorrectly.

By doing `test += letters.pop();` you are appending `letters.pop()` to `test`.

Instead you should prepend `letters.pop()` to `test`:

```
test = letters.pop() + test;
```

Comment: What a silly mistake! I cannot believe it was that simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:
if(Character.compare(guess, (char) letters.peek())){
.
Existing logic
.
}

Comment: Thank you for you answer, unfortunately this does not work and is a bit irrelevant to the my question. Again, thank you for your answer!

Comment: `if((Object)guess == letters.peek()){
      test += letters.pop();
      score++;
   }
   else{
      test += letters.pop();
      score--;
   }` ------------------------- Here, you are comparing 's' with the top element of the stack 'e'. Hope this helps.